# Valid Query, Failed View

Tags: sql, view, db2

I have had an issue with some DB2 SQL and could really use some help.

In short, people want me to create a view. I wrote a query that works and returns what we wanted... but when I wrap it with a 'CREATE VIEW' statement, the view throws errors when I query it with anything.

The query is (names changed obviously):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "QTable"."Add" "Q_Add", "QTable"."Approved" "Q_Approved", "QTable"."Link" "Q_Link"
 FROM (( 
SELECT * FROM db.schema.VTable) 
 "QTable" LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM db.schema.ETable) 
"QStat" on "QTable"."Status" = "QStat"."ETable")
```

Each time I run this I get 10 record back. Awesome, that's what I want. When I wrap it as a View, which I do by entering:

```
CREATE VIEW TestSchema.TestTable AS
SELECT * FROM ( *query I just wrote above*)
```

It runs (very quickly) but then I run a basic `SELECT * FROM viewname` I always get the same error of:

```
SQL0206N  "QTable.Status" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703
```

I have been stuck for a while now. I am assuming I am creating the view wrong. Any ideas? Tips?

Edit: DB2 11.1

Comment: What version of DB2?

Comment: DB2 11.1, added it to the description.

Comment: Make sure QTable is **always** written between double quotes, as in `"QTable"`. See my response. I was forced to change the query, so it would work. You missed one case.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is in quotes in my SQL. The QTable right before left outer join. I am not sure why it worked when I ran Tomc's code as opposed to mine or yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of just about ll the brackets and quotes. I suspect they are not necessary, unless DB2 is very non-standard sql. I've left the quotes in although I would take all of those out as well unless they are reserved words.

There is no reason to do something like `from (select * from table)`

The query should just be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "QTable"."Add" "Q_Add", "QTable"."Approved" "Q_Approved", "QTable"."Link" "Q_Link"
FROM db.schema.VTable QTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  db.schema.ETable "QStat" on "QTable"."Status" = "QStat"."ETable"
```

Your view then should also not be `create view as select * from (...)` it should just be:

```
create view myView as
SELECT DISTINCT "QTable"."Add" "Q_Add", "QTable"."Approved" "Q_Approved", "QTable"."Link" "Q_Link"
FROM db.schema.VTable QTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  db.schema.ETable "QStat" on "QTable"."Status" = "QStat"."ETable"
```

Comment: Yes, DB2 uses standard SQL syntax (most of the time) so the query will greatly benefit from the simplification you are showing. Upvoting.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.
Also, I did try just doing the second tip you mentioned and removing the SELECT * FROM (...) and it seems it was redundant but didn't fix anything.

Comment: So that worked... but I am not entirely sure why. Also, I apologize for the terribly ugly code. I am not the best with SQL and a lot of the meat of my SQL is coming from a program that is helping generate it for my tables.
Also this is scary.. because I have 23 tables to do these changes for and some are 500 lines. 
Either way, thank you very much and if you can think of the reason, why did that change and simplification fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a different problem. I just tried it in DB2 10.5 and it works well:

```
create table vtable (
  "Add" int,
  "Approved" int,
  "Link" varchar(20),
  "Status" int
);

create table etable (
  "ETable" int
);

create view my_view1 as
select
  *
from
  (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT "QTable"."Add" "Q_Add",
      "QTable"."Approved" "Q_Approved",
      "QTable"."Link" "Q_Link"
    FROM
      (
          ( SELECT * FROM VTable) "QTable"
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          (
            SELECT
              *
            FROM ETable
          )
          "QStat" on "QTable"."Status" = "QStat"."ETable"
      )
  )
```

Anyway, you have excessive parenthesis. Remove the ones you don't need.

And QTable need to be in double quotes always, as in `"QTable"`.